# Laravel:Attempt to read property "name" on int

Tags: php, laravel

i have problem this code, and I'm confused about how to resolve this error, please help me

Attempt to read property "name" on int
this code my controller :

```
public function index()
    {
        $dataguru = DataGuru::all();
        $datasiswa = DataSiswa::all();
        $perusahaan = Perusahaan::all();
        $jurusan = Jurusan::all();
       $reportdata = ReportData::with('siswa', 'guru', 'perusahaan', 'jurusan', 'wilayah')->get();

        return view('admin.report-data.index', compact('reportdata', 'dataguru', 'datasiswa', 'jurusan', 'perusahaan'));
    }
```

this is my model :

```
class ReportData extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        "perusahaan",
        "siswa",
        "wilayah",
        "guru",
        "jurusan",
    ];

    public function perusahaan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Perusahaan::class, 'perusahaan');
    }
    
    public function wilayah()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Perusahaan::class, 'wilayah');
    }

    public function siswa()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(DataSiswa::class, 'siswa');
    }

    public function guru()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(DataGuru::class, 'guru');
    }

    public function jurusan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Jurusan::class, 'jurusan');
    }
}
```

this is my views/blade :

```
@forelse ($reportdata as $item)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $loop->index + 1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->siswa->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->perusahaan->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->perusahaan->wilayah  }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->dataguru->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->jurusan->jurusan  }}</td>
```

I'm having problems with this, I hope friends can help me

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue has to do with your relationships `public funtction perusahaan` having the same name as the column `perusahaan`. Since models pull their properties from the database, `$item->perusahaan` would be a number, i.e. the value in the database, and not the relationship. Typically, you'd do `public function perusahaan()`, and use a column like `perusahaan_id` to connect them. Try renaming your relationships, or changing the column name, and your code should work.

Comment: (I say _should_ work, since `belongsTo()` can return `null`, and `$item->perusahaan->name` _could_ evaluate to `$item->null->name`, which is also not valid, but would trigger a different error. You're coding in a way that is assuming that _every instance of `$item` has an associated `siswa`, `perusahaan`, `dataguru` **and** `jurusan`_, but if any of them do not, your code will fail. `$item->siswa?->name ?? 'N/A'`, or other safe coding should be applied to this)